# do all elements from an array satisfy certain condition determined by another string array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

Sorry for the title but I don't know hot to explain briefly what I need to do.

I have this predefined array :

```
string[] SkippedAreasArray = new string[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G",
            "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q"};
```

We can call each letter `Area`. We have a variable `NumberOfAreas` which holds an integer value from 0(null) to 17. The meaning of this value is this. If `NumberOfAreas` = 5 then we have string `"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"`. If `NumberOfAreas` = 3 then we have `"A", "B", "C"` and so on. The string always begins with `"A"` and follow the alphabetical order.

The user input is the so called `SkippedAreas` array. It can contains random letters, which can not be duplicated and are in the range `A-Q`.

What is the idea - If we have `SkippedAreas` array = `"A", "C"` and `NumberOfAreas` = 5 or `"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"` then we have to keep the `NumberOfAreas` equal to 5 by skipping the letter `"A"` and `"C"` and adding the next two letters so the `NumberOfAreas` becomes- `"B", "D", "E", "F", "G"`.

We can only skip a letter(area) that is already in the range of `NumerOfAreas` for example if we get the base example when `NumerOfAreas` = 5 and the string is `"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"` we can only skip a letter that is one of those 5 letters. However by skipping any letter we open access to the next in row so if the first time we skip `"A"` we are free to use `"F"` for the next round and if `"F"` is part from the user input string `SkippedAreas` then it's legal to skip `"F"` and open `"G"`.

I need an algorithm with which I will be able to validate the user input.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use LINQ

```
var FilteredAreas = 
    ListOfAreas.Where(a => !SkippedAreas.Contains(a)).Take(NumberOfAreas);
```

Comment: You were too fase :) Should consider using `ToList()` to evaluate results just once, but the idea is clear and simple.

Comment: I may be mistaken since I'm not very good at reading LINQ but as I understand we take `NumberOfAreas` only once and it is actually a dynamic value - if we skip an are from `NumberOfAreas` we add the next letter (in alphabetical order) and then the check should include this new letter.

Comment: @Leron not sure I have understood you. Please clarify a bit further. As is this query just takes all areas from `ListOfAreas`, filter out those which are in `SkippedAreas` and only than it takes first `NumberOfAreas`. If you are going to change the contents of any of this variables, you just re-run the query to get actual result.