# Dynamicly remove and add another letter from a List<> keeping alphabetical order

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I have this predefined string array :

```
string[] SkippedAreasArray = new string[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G",
            "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q"};
```

And according to an user input I populate a `List<string>` like this :

```
List<String> UsedAreas = new List<String>();
int RangeOfInput = (int)entity.AreasCnt;
UsedAreas = SkippedAreasArray.ToList().GetRange(0, RangeOfInput);
```

Also from an user input I get another string containing non-duplicated letters from `A to Q` (like in `SkippedAreasArray`).

The array is formed like this :

```
SkippedAreasFromForm = (txtSkippedAreas.Text).ToUpper().Split(',');
```

What I do is first - sorting the `SkippedAreasFromForm` :

```
Array.Sort<string>(SkippedAreasFromForm);
```

And then I need the following :

```
foreach (string tempAreaValue in SkippedAreasFromForm)
{
    if (UsedAreas.Contains(tempAreaValue))
    {

    }
    else 
    { 

    }
}
```

if the `List<> UsedAreas` contains the letter that is checked I want to remove this letter from the List and at the same time to add the next letter that follows in alphabetical order.

P.S

I see now that my goal is not clear here so I'll explain the meaning of this :

`SkippedAreasFromForm` is an user input that should be validated and that's the idea to want this algorithm. If in some case `if (UsedAreas.Contains(tempAreaValue))` returns false then the input is wrong and I need to return error message.

Comment: How it differs from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749935/do-all-elements-from-an-array-satisfy-certain-condition-determined-by-another-st)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ to Objects to achieve that without looping:

```
UsedAreas = SkippedAreasArray.Except(SkippedAreasFromForm)
                             .OrderBy(e => e)
                             .Take(RangeOfInput)
                             .ToList();
```

It's taking `RangeOfInput` elements from `SkippedAreasArray` that are not in `SkippedAreasFromForm`. Result is `List<string>`.

*Update*

You can check your error message condition that way:

```
if(SkippedAreasFromForm.Except(SkippedAreasArray.Take(RangeOfInput)).Any())
{
    // incorrect user input
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I see that I'm misleading due to not explaining the idea behind this. Please read the edited post.

Comment: Honestly - I don't understand this LINQ query but it works. Thanks.

Comment: I would not use `Count() > 0` but `Any()` which breaks as soon as the query returns one element whereas `Count` needs to execute the whole query.

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<string> usedAreas = SkippedAreasArray.Take(RangeOfInput);
IEnumerable<string> skippedAreasFromForm = (txtSkippedAreas.Text).ToUpper()
    .Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
IEnumerable<string> invalids = skippedAreasFromForm.Except(usedAreas);
if (invalids.Any())
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("These are invalid: [{0}]", 
        string.Join(",", invalids.OrderBy(sa => sa))));
```